# Buttons on the new presented view are not working when we use presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, presentmodalviewcontroller, ibaction

button actions are not working when i use **presentModalViewController**

**in view 1:**

-

```
(void)PreseentTheNextView
    {
        NSLog(@"clicked to add the new view from botom to top");
        PreferenceViewController *prefDetails=[[PreferenceViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PreferenceViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:prefDetails animated:YES];
    }
```

I have **two buttons** on the **PreferenceViewController**

**In View 2:**

```
-(IBAction)button1Click
{
NSLog(@"Button 1 Clicked");
}


-(IBAction)button2Click
{
 NSLog(@"Button 2 Clicked");
}

-(IBAction)DismissButton
    {
     NSLog(@"Remove/ Dismiss down the view to previus page ");
    }
```

All these buttons are set in IB of PreferenceViewController.

And these button actions are not working when i use **presentModalViewController**

And works fine if i used **Navigation PushViewController**.

But our requirement is only present the view from bottom to top

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this...

```
  [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:prefDetails animated:YES]; instead of 
   [self presentModalViewController:prefDetails animated:YES];
```